# How to Embed a PowerBI Tile in a Rails app? (and apply filter to it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, devise, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm struggling with this since a week... I have tried so many things, read so many documentations (walkthrougsh), I can't find any solutions and I have lost the clarity. I really need your help.

- I have created a simple Rails app.
- I have a Power BI account and a Azure account.
- I'm using an example set of data on PowerBI (Retail Analysis Sample).

I want my users to signin on my app (through devise), then access to some pages and see embedded PowerBI Tiles (or report, or dashboard maybe). Then I want them to be able to filter the results. A client-side example is https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/filters.html.
I want to be able to do the same.

I'm lost with all the client id, secret, ressource uri, ressource url, ...
What solution/walkthrough must I use?

Thank you so much for your time

Fro

Answer (score 1):

> New tile API allows to integrate content from a user’s Power BI
>   account into application UI  for tiles that are on a user’s
>   dashboards. You can leverage this to add personalized BI content from
>   your user’s Power BI account into your application.

See [documentation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-api-updates-roundup/)
A [Sample application](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/embed-a-tile-into-an-app)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Power Bi Embedded [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/).  This will allow you to control who can see what content from within your application without having to authenticate with the Power Bi service.  Power Bi Embedded is an azure service that allows you to upload pbix files which are then subsequently available for view by using an "Access key" to get a token to view the report.  I know it works well for displaying "Reports," I am not sure about just showing "Tiles."  They recently released RLS and some new Javascript SDK for more advanced features like filtering, check that [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-whats-new/).

Hope this helps.